# Concrete5 Dynamic select list on user account / add user page

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-5.7

I want to add a form select input on the user account page / add user page with a dynamic list of options / values.

I know how to get the dynamic list form a database table and create a dynamic list for the select options.

```
echo $form->select('clientsID', $indexed_array, '0');
```

Question: Where and how to add this to the account/add user page and save this to the user table?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well you need a **User Attribute**. It will be saved automatically in the `UserInfo` and if you set the options correctly it will be displayed on the user account page / add user page.

Note that all the following code should go in a Controller file in `/application/controllers` or even better inside a package. How to create a package is well documented [here](http://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/packages/overview). That way your site can be updated without any problems.

Your associative array with dynamic values from a DB table or other sources to be filled in the **User Attribute** (a Dropdown in this case):

```
$options = array(
    'foo' => 'Foo',
    'bar' => 'Bar',
    'baz' => 'Baz'
);
```

Attributes parameters:

```
$selectArgs = array(
    'akHandle' => 'my_select',
    'akName' => t('my Select'), // t() is for translation
    'uakProfileDisplay' => true, // Will be displayed on the Users Profile page
    'uakMemberListDisplay' => true, // Will be displayed on the dashboard members page
    'uakProfileEdit' => true, // A memeber is able to edit the attribute
    'uakProfileEditRequired' => true, // The attribute MUST be filled with a value
    'uakRegisterEdit' => true, // Will be displayed on the Register Page
    'uakRegisterEditRequired' => true, // The attribute MUST be filled with a value upon registration
    'akIsSearchableIndexed' => true, // The attribute will be indexed (searchable)
    'akSelectAllowOtherValues' => false, // A user may add/remove other options to the select attribute
    'akSelectOptionDisplayOrder' => 'alpha_asc', // the display order
    'akIsSearchable' => true // one can search by these options
);
```

Classes used:

```
use \Concrete\Core\Attribute\Type as AttributeType;
use UserAttributeKey;
use Concrete\Attribute\Select\Option;
```

Define the Attribute Type:

```
$attrSelect = AttributeType::getByHandle('select');
```

Check if the Attribute already exists and if not, create it:

```
$mySelect = UserAttributeKey::getByHandle($selectArgs['akHandle'])

if(!is_object($mySelect)) {
    UserAttributeKey::add($attrSelect, $selectArgs);
    $mySelect = UserKey::getByHandle($args_address['akHandle']);
}
```

And finally fill the options into the select:

```
foreach($options as $value) {
    Option::add($mySelect, t($value));        
}
```